# Ruby Cucumber PDF reader

Tags: ruby, cucumber, pdf-reader

I'm running tests to render and check a PDF.  I've got it working but the PDF's are date stamped in the filename.  I'm looking for a way to always have today's generated file to be opened.  I've tried the `Date.today` approach but had no joy as PDF reader doesn't see it as a correct filename. Here is my code so you can see what I'm trying to do:

```
today = Date.today
Given /^I open the saved PDF and confirm the VRM is "(.*?)"$/ do |vrm|
filename = 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\vehicle_summary_VRM_#{today}.pdf'
    PDF::Reader.open(filename) do |reader|  
        reader.pages.each do |page|
            expect(reader.page(1)).to have_content vrm
                puts page.text
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following exception: `input must be an IO-like object or a filename (ArgumentError)`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What date format do you expect to be in `filename`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change single quotes in:

```
filename = 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\vehicle_summary_VRM_#{today}.pdf'
```

to double quotes:

```
filename = "C:\Users\user\Downloads\vehicle_summary_VRM_#{today}.pdf"
```